# Rotate image programmatically from other view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, image-rotation

i'm developing an iPhone application using swift to communicate with a device via bluetooth. First, i have a bluetoothViewController() to receive data and SingleAxisViewController() to display and animate the data received. Following are my codes so far

BluetoothViewController

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth
import Foundation

class BluetoothViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate,CBPeripheralDelegate,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,ValueChangedDelegate {

struct DataReceived {
    static var Parameter_1: Double = 90
}
      .
      .
      .
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic!, error: NSError!) {

var hashedData = characteristic.value

//Conversion hashedData into Double type

DataReceived.Parameter_1 = Double(hashedData)

let singleaxisview = SingeAxisViewController()
singleaxisview.delegate = self
singleaxisview.valueChangedNotifyEveryone()
}

func valueChanged(nValue : String)
{
    println("do nothing")
    print(nValue)
}
```

Parameter1ViewController

```
import UIKit
import CoreGraphics

protocol ValueChangedDelegate
{
   func valueChanged(nValue : String)
}

class SingeAxisViewController: UIViewController {
var delegate : ValueChangedDelegate?
@IBOutlet weak var Needle: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setAnchorPoint()
    var image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "arrow")!
    Needle = UIImageView(image: image)
}

func valueChangedNotifyEveryone()
{
        angle = BluetoothViewController.DataReceived.Parameter_1
        var image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "arrow")!
        Needle = UIImageView(image: image)
        Needle.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((CGFloat(angle*14.2) * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180.0))              
        }

func setAnchorPoint() {
        angle = BluetoothViewController.DataReceived.Parameter_1
        Needle.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((CGFloat(angle*14.2) * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180.0))
     }
```

So my problem is when I go into `Parameter1ViewController` the image can rotate and works. But when the bluetooth value changes, the function `valueChangedNotifyEveryone()` is fired and error occurs:

> found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

at

```
 Needle.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((CGFloat(angle*14.2) * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180.0))
```

Can someone suggest why?

Comment: have you set the following outlet in Storyboard / xib? `@IBOutlet weak var Needle`

Comment: hi, i have get the problem solved, i guess apple don't allow to make changes on UI from other viewcontroller